# multiple Custom cell with identifier - reload table - low memory

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management

I have `UITableView` which use custom cells. In total 5 different type of cell identifier.

I nib file related-  CustomCell `.h` and `.m` file. Which provide several label and images.

In storyborad I have created 5 `UITableViewCell` and subclass with this `CustomCell.h` but with different identifier. Every cell may use some label or image from `CustomCell.h`

Everytime I use `[self.tableview reloadData];` It create new cell in memorry.

CustomeCell can not dequeue which leads to Low memory and Eventually app crash. IS this correct?

**Every time `[self.tableview reloadData];` called, new cell added to memory instead of reusing them. How do I release older cell?**

**[UPDATE with images]**

---

In View controller Table view with customer cell with different Identifier

[image]

One of them is like below.
[image]

TableView Row

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier = [self calculateIdentifier:indexPath.row];// This will retrun Identifier @"LabelCell" etc.

    ControlCell *cell = (ControlCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    cell.questionLabel.text = [self calculateQue:indexPath.row];
    cell.answerLabel.text = [self calculateAns:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Visibly increasing memory and app crashing is not good. Your table should be reusing existing cells that were already allocated in memory. That's the whole point of UITableView. It might help if you shared your table's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and perhaps the rest of the view controller's .m file.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I will update with more information!!

Comment: @Aaron I have update question with CustomeCell nib, Storyboard tableview and cellForRowAtIndexPath method!

Comment: What are you loading into that web view? How do you load your images?

Comment: Same as cell.myImageView = [Self getImage:indexPath.row];// return image from database: However this will only apply for relavant cell where image required. currently I don't even have data on webview. However it most likely it will be some custom html code.

Comment: OK - Have you tried opening Instrument using the Leaks template to see exactly what's going on with the memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55993/discussion-between-nitya-and-aaron).